# Java: Map SQL select from multiple tables into multiple entities

Tags: java, oracle

I need to execute the following query:

```
select a.*, b.* from tableA a, tableB b;
```

having `tableA` and `tableB` some fields with the same name (such as `id`, `created_at`, `created_by`).

And in my java code I have already mapped the `tableA` and `tableB` entities (in 2 different clases).

So I'd like to be able to somehow map the result set directly to both my entities, but I'm not able to figure out how. And also, even if I could do that, oracle does not  return 2 different fields with the same name, but instead it renames them with a number at the end.

Is there any clean and fancy way to do what I need?

Comment: How you have mapped those entities to table? Are you using any ORM?

Comment: You have no relation between the result sets, so do that in two `SELECT`s.

Comment: Are you really trying to do a cross join between the `A` and `B` tables?  If so, then the immediately above comment should be one way to do this.  If not, then tell us what the join relationship might be.

Comment: We're using hibernate in our application, but this time we need to execute a complex query so we need to do it as a native one. Also, we don't have any relationship in our entities (but we do have a relationship in the tables) between themselves, and I can't add that relationship because our entities are in our app core, and the query has stuff that does not belong to core.